# Change the value of the variable based on another variable

Tags: angular

As the example below, when changing "a", I want "b" to also change,
I'm using a method that uses the onfocusout function to capture the change event of "a" input, but is there any build-in way ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{a}}
      a: <input [(ngModel)]="a" />
      b: <input [(ngModel)]="b" />
    </div>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  a = 0;
  b = this.a + 1; 
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331171/angular-5-auto-update-string-variable-on-another-variable-change?noredirect=1#comment89638194_51331171

Answer (score 0):

As a quick fix the below can be used

```
 <div>
    {{a}}
    a: <input [(ngModel)]="a" />
    b: <input [value]="+a + 1" />
  </div>
```