# Angular 5 - Detect changes on the variables

Tags: angular

I know...there is plenty of topics like this, but I checked tons of topics and none of then applies to my issue: You can detect changes of the properties of component, you can perform a DoCheck, but the variable must be array or iterable (cannot be a simple string for example). Also can use Subject , but to set the variable you need to use a method and for some reason I don't know how to grab the value after that. Anyway, I need something very simple: A solution identical to $watch of AngularJS: Something that's stay observing any kind of change on the variable..Something that can fit on this scenario:

```
import {Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
  }
  myVar = {
products : ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie', 'Alpha' ],
dummy: 'Hello'
};
removeItem(i) {
  this.myVar.products.splice(i,1);
}
setDummy() {
  this.myVar.dummy = 'Hi !';
}
addNewKey() {
 this.myVar['newKey'] = 'Yellow';
}
addnewArray() {
  this.myVar['colors'] = ['Yellow', 'Pink', 'Blue'];
}
}
```

No matter what of change on myVar, I'd like to track it. How to archive it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51331171/angular-5-auto-update-string-variable-on-another-variable-change/51331820#51331820

Answer (score 1):

A few options come to mind:

1) You could use NgRx. It does a great job of providing notifications every time your data is changed ... but it is a big step adding NgRx to your application.

2) You could build a service to manage the array. The array would be private in that service and every component that needs the array would need to inject the service. The service can then provide the options to add/remove so you would always know when those actions occur.

You could then use a Subject or BehaviorSubject to provide notifications every time that the array was modifed.

3) Depending on what needs to be notified of the change, you can leverage Angular's built-in change detection. But that is only reflected in properties bound in a template.

As an example of #2 above:

```
export class ProductService {
    private productsUrl = 'api/products';

    private selectedProductSource = new BehaviorSubject<IProduct | null>(null);
    selectedProductChanges$ = this.selectedProductSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    changeSelectedProduct(selectedProduct: IProduct | null): void {
        this.selectedProductSource.next(selectedProduct);
    }

}
```

In this code I am tracking the "selected product" and sending out notifications when it has been changed.

You'd need to change this code to watch for changes to your `myVar` object. Instead of a `changeSelectedProduct`, you'd have your removeItem, setDummy, addXXX methods. Each of those methods could call `.next` to provide notification of the change.

Comment: Thanks ! but as I mentioned...using subject, you need to set the variable using the next method. I can't work in this way..I really need a very simple thing, like the old $watch

Comment: Feel free to post a change request at https://github.com/angular/angular. But if you don't want to wait ... you'll need to use one of the suggestions above. I don't understand how you can't "work in this way"? AFAIK, there is no simpler way right now.

Comment: Longs story @deboraK, I need to create components for VR systems. This works in a very weird way...A external program will inject an object inside the window object and I need to detect such changes :( Not an usual scenario. But thanks !!!